# Xcode different View for iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, storyboard

I`m using a storyboard in my app, and storyboards requires iOS 5.

What happened when an iOS 4 Device opens my app?

Can I put code in viewDidLoad for iOS 4 Devices?

I want to create a specific View for iOS 4, that says "iOS 5 Required"
is that possible?

Can I use something like this to check if device running iOS 4 or lower?:

```
BOOL iOS4 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] <= 5.0;
```

And can I put something like this in `viewDidLoad` ?

```
if(iOS4) {
    // i´m changing view to my "iOS 5 Required" view (XIB File)
}
```

I don't have an iOS 4 device, does this work?

Comment: it can be done, but I really think that it is better to let people know beforehand that the app requires ios5 -- BEFOREHAND (in the store that it is) -- sorry I dont see the value, I revoked my original answer therefore too

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the version of iOS supports storyboards:

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"UIStoryboard")) {
    //iOS is supporting storyboards (iOS >= 5.0)

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];  

   //use your storyboard
}else{
    //iOS is not supporting storyboards
    //load viewcontrollers from nib
}
```

However, I don't think Apple will like this idea. They might reject your app for doing so. I'm not surprised if there's some section in the guidelines telling you not to do this.

Comment: yip, which is why I revoked my answer but technically this is correct -- so +1

Answer (score 0):

the app wont be installable under ios4 when it NEEDS storyboards...
this is shown in the appstore unless you REALLY want it otherwise

Comment: ok, in my AppDelegate.h or .m i type something like:  if (os<5){ View *view = [[View alloc] initWithNibName:@"xibNameGoesHere" bundle:nil];
view.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController: view animated:YES]; }

Comment: I didnt do this as it is not good... I really think that it is better to let people know beforehand that the app requires ios5 -- BEFOREHAND (in the store that it is) -- sorry I dont see the value

Answer (score 0):

You can get the OS version using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

However, you should avoid relying on the version string as an indication of device or OS capabilities. There is usually a more reliable method of checking whether a particular feature or class is available. For example, you can check if UIPopoverController is available on the current device using NSClassFromString:

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController")) {
    // Do something
}
```

Some classes, like CLLocationManager and UIDevice, provide methods to check device capabilities:

```
if([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
    // Do something
}
```

Apple uses systemVersion in their GLSprite sample code, so my recommendation can't be absolute:

```
// A system version of 3.1 or greater is required to use CADisplayLink. The NSTimer
// class is used as fallback when it isn't available.
NSString *reqSysVer = @"3.1";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
    displayLinkSupported = TRUE;
```

And if the  currSysVer is not higher than the reqSysVer, just make an else statement that automatically presents a new modalViewController that says "Needs iOS 5"

Comment: nice tips, no answer ...

Comment: How is that not an answer. You can use the last block of code to find out the iOS version of the device. If the iOS version is less than 5.0, then in the if statement call a method that switches the views. This site does not exist to code your apps for you, but to answer your questions. This is simply an answer to one possible way this can be done, if you don't think it is an answer, then I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: getting the OS version is not the point -- his app wouldnt even load because it wont load the viewcontroller coming from the storyboard under ios4. so it is even wrong. -- he would need to conditionally set a different rootViewController in his application:didFinishLaunching